# Ocaml list recursion

Tags: recursion, ocaml

This is what I have for my code so far:

```
let equiv = [];;
let unequiv = [];;

let rec isEqual equiv unequiv compareVal x lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | a::b -> 
    if x a compareVal = true then 
      (a :: isEqual equiv unequiv compareVal x b :: equiv) 
      @ (isEqual equiv unequiv (List.hd unequiv) x unequiv)
    else 
      a :: isEqual equiv unequiv compareVal x b :: unequiv
```

However when I run it gives me an error:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'a list list
       The type variable 'a list occurs inside 'a list list
```

My intended output should look something like this : `[[a,v,c],[s,f,t]]`

Is there a flaw in my logic?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is hard to read, you should decompose it:

From what I understand, if your list is not empty, you check if `x a compareVal` is `true`, this can be simplified as `if x a compareVal`.

In that case you put the head of your list in front of a recursive call where almost everything remains the same except `lst` that is transformed into `b :: equiv` and you append this list to a recursive call with `compareVal` being equal to the head of `unequiv`and the recursive call being applied to `unequiv`.

In the other case, you just append the head of your list to a recursive call in which only the checked list is modified.

What can we know from your code?

- Since you wrote `a :: b`, `a` is of type `'a` and `b` of type `'a list`
- You write `x a compareVal = true` so `x` is of type `'a -> 'b -> bool` and `compareVal` is of type `'b`
- `a :: isEqual ...` means that `isEqual` returns an element of type `'a list`
- `b :: equiv` is used as the `lst` argument of your function so its type should be the same as `a :: b` but here is the problem, `b` is used as a head in `b :: equiv` so its type is `'a` and as the tail in `a :: b` so its type is `'a list`. This type is infinitely recursive and OCaml won't let you do that (for good reasons).

Try to write exactly what you want, to divide it in smaller problems and to write your code accordingly or you'll be lost rapidly.